# Django ORM query to exclude grouped by row if certain conditions are met (postgresql)

Tags: django, postgresql, group-by, distinct, django-orm

This is about an application that enables some functionality for collaborative moderation, kinda similar to Stackoverflow.

### Current State

I have a Django ORM query like this:

```
versions = Version.objects.filter(is_reviewed=False).exclude(moderations__user__pk=request.user.id).order_by('content_type__id', 'object_id', '-number').distinct('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Each content object can have an arbitrary number of versions created by users. What i am doing here is to get all non-reviewed versions that are from other users, but only the most recent one per content object.

### Problem

But i want to add another exclusion condition: If a content object has a newer version with `is_reviewed=True` it should not return the previous versions. Newer ones that are not reviewed should be returned though. Any idea how to do this?

Some examples. I am assuming that all versions here are for the same content object.

**Example A**

1. "First version" - not reviewed
2. "Improved version" - not reviewed
3. "Even more improved version" - not reviewed

This should return the third row. Works as expected.

**Example B**

1. "First version" - **reviewed**
2. "Improved version" - not reviewed
3. "Even more improved version" - not reviewed

This should return the third row. Works as expected.

**Example C**

1. "First version" - not reviewed
2. "Improved version" - **reviewed**
3. "Even more improved version" - not reviewed

This should return the third row. Works as expected.

**Example D**

1. "First version" - not reviewed
2. "Improved version" - not reviewed
3. "Even more improved version" - **reviewed**

This should return **no row**. This does not work at the moment. It will return the second row which is not what it's intended to do.

/edit

Here is my model: http://sql.nopaste.dk/p48981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to write queryset methods that help explain what we are trying to do, and work backwards from there.

```
Version.objects.newest_by_content_type().unreviewed()
```

Then, we just need the queryset/manager methods. [Note: I'm using the pattern described at [Building a higher-level query API](http://dabapps.com/blog/higher-level-query-api-django-orm/) to add these methods onto the query set].

Which, as it turns out, is the code you have already written, just ordered slightly differently.

```
def newest_by_content_type(self):
    return self.order_by('content_type__id', 'object_id', '-updated').distinct('content_type', 'object_id')

def unreviewed(self):
    return self.filter(is_reviewed=False)
```

Then, you can do other things with this query set. Like remove ones owned by the current user, for instance.

The previous incarnation of this answer discussed an alternative solution, using a `superseded_by`, or `supersedes` self-relationship:

```
class Version(models.Model):
    supersedes = models.ForeignKey('Version', 
        related_name='superseded_by', null=True, blank=True)
```

Then, you can get all non-superseded objects by:

```
Version.objects.filter(superseded_by=None)
```

Depending upon constraints, it may make sense to use a `OneToOneField` for the superseded relationship: if a version can only be superseded by at most one version, and a version may only supersede one version. It's also possible to use this, along with HTTP headers and to return `412 Precondition Failed` when an already superseded object is attempted to be superseded again, for instance. This would make sense where a version chain is 'straight', and does not allow for branches.

Comment: i also needed the information before your edit and added a `superseded_by` field to the `Version` model. looks really good in combination with the higher level query api methods